# Specify Activity to launch in Android menu xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-menu

It would be great if I could specify which Activity to launch in the menu xml file, instead of having to override `onOptionsItemSelected` for every class that uses this method.  It seems there could be something that could be done to implement this a bit more elegantly.  Are there any solutions that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is an [ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionProvider.html).

You would specify an ActionProvider and that provider would implement whatever action you want such as launching an activity / sending an intent

Answer (score 0):

You could override `onOptionsItemSelected` in your base activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_launch_settings:
                //TODO Launch settings 
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Then in every `menu.xml` file that you want to launch Setting include the `action_launch_settings` item

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_launch_settings"
    android:title="Launch Settings"
    />
```

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question, I think this is exactly what he wants to avoid

Comment: Refactoring into a base class is an option, but due to the lack of multiple inheritance, it might be the wrong tool to use in a more complex class hierarchy.  I want to avoid code alltogether (or steer away from the standard onOptionsItemSelected methodology.